# C - Segmentation fault assigning to char *

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
/*Reverse all strings with pointers in str*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char * str[] = {
                "To err is human...",
                "But to really mess things up...",
                "One needs to know C!!"
                };

    void xstrrev(char *);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        xstrrev(str[i]);

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);

    return(0);
}

void xstrrev(char * s)
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[strlen(s)+1];
    while(*(s + i) != '\0')
        {
            str[i] = *(s + i);
            i++;
        }
    str[i] = '\0';

    i = 0; 
    while(*(s+i) != '\0')
    {   
        //printf("%c\t%c\n", *(s + i), str[strlen(s) -i -1]);
        *(s + i) = str[strlen(s) -i -1];
        i++;
    }   
}
```

When I compile with gcc (version 4.8.2 ) and debug with gdb (version 7.7.1)
I get

```
Starting program: /home/aditya/Documents/Programming/C/strrev 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048571 in xstrrev (s=0x8048620 "To err is human...") at strrev.c:39
39          *(s + i) = str[strlen(s) -i -1];
```

But I don't understand why. This has happened whenever I try to *assign something using char pointers* and *while using array of pointers to strings*. I tried uncommenting line the 5th last line and commenting the 4th last. I get the expected results without any error.
Pls help.

Comment: You are modifying a string literal, string literals are non modifiable.

Comment: Why are you prototyping a function inside `main`?

Answer (score 0):

The strings defined at compile-time are allocated in your code segment and can't be written to.

To achieve what you're trying to do you will need to allocate buffers for your strings using `malloc`, copy your strings there and reverse these buffers rather than the original string literals.